# For Loop Display Fact

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out why I am getting a undefined offset of 1 for this for loop I'm writting. I have an array ($facts) that has specific key values pairs and I'm trying to see if on each iteration the $i matches one of the keys in the array. If the key isset and in the array I need to display the value of that key.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
  if (isset($i) && in_array($i, $facts[$i])) {
    echo $facts[$i];
  }
  echo $i;
}
```

UPDATE: Use the function isset to test if the incremented value equals one of the keys in the $facts array. If there is a key that matches, display the value after the number.

Comment: Perhaps `isset($facts[$i])` rather than simply `isset($i)`... `$i` is definitely set, because that's the value defined and incremented in your `for` loop

Comment: ...and `in_array($i, $facts[$i])` will check if that integer exists as a value in `$facts[$i]` (which probably will fail since `$facts[$i]` probably isn't an array, anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the correct way of checking (removing the `in_array()`).

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    echo $i; // Now the number is first.
    if (isset($facts[$i])) {
        // This is only echoed if $i exists as a key.
        echo $facts[$i];
    }
}
```

If you only want to show the number if the fact exists, move `echo $i` inside the if-statement (or better yet, use `foreach($facts as $key => $value)` in that case).

Answer (score 0):

You could check `$facts[$i]`

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
  if (isset($facts[$i]) && in_array($i, $facts[$i])) {
    echo $facts[$i];
  }
  echo $i;
}
```